# What is the strongest chess engine working on Arduino (Atmega328)?

Tags: engines

What is the strongest chess engine working on [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino)? Or does any engine work on it?

Answer (score 2):

Not every chess engine works on Arduino as it doesn't run a conventional *nix operating system.

There's a list of chess engines that do work here:

<strike>http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Arduino</strike>

Updated url from Fabian's comment:

https://www.chessprogramming.org/Arduino#Chess_Programs

Comment: Since the chess programming wiki has moved, the URL is not working any more. The new one is https://www.chessprogramming.org/Arduino#Chess_Programs.